# socketio connects with polling after a websocket connection is established. blocks communication

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, xmlhttprequest, flask-socketio

I've been struggling with a strange problem with my websocket connection.
I use socketio 1.4.5 to connect to the server (flask, flask-socketio, gunicorn, nginx).

The problem is that about 1 of 8 connection attempts socketio connects using xhr polling **after** the websocket connection is established. Somehow this blocks the whole communication for this specific client. When timeout is reached (60seconds in my case) socketio connects again and if no xhr-polling is blocking the next time, the communication is up again.

This i very frustrating. and i have never seen this problem earlier on application with the same setup.

```
?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=997d6d19758641249e3b1232341e9fe2 GET 101 websocket   localhost       websocket   Other   0 B 1.0 min 

?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LEUZRW7&sid=997d6d19758641249e3b1232341e9fe2 GET 504 http/1.1    localhost   127.0.0.1:443   xhr socket.io-1.4.5.js:1    763 B   1.0 min
```

The two lines above is what is available on the network tab when analyzing the trafic in chrome. Before the timeout is reached, 504 is replaced with "pending".

I have been trying to find the solution for this for a couple of hours now, and running out of ideas. I hope someone can help me with this..

Comment: I think this means that the websocket connection dropped. The client is trying to reconnect, which normally involves connecting via polling first, then upgrading to websocket.

Comment: usually this reconnect happens instantly. Why does the new polling-connnection need to timeout before everything is OK? Is it somehow possible to get more detailed information from flask-socketio?

Comment: You can add `engineio_logger=True` to your `SocketIO` constructor to have more information dumped to the console